# Generics, overload resolution and delegates (sorry, can't find a better title)

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, overload-resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Func<T> ambiguous with Func<IEnumerable<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573011/why-is-funct-ambiguous-with-funcienumerablet)

I noticed a very weird overload resolution issue with generics...

Consider the following methods:

```
static void Foo<TSource>(TSource element, Func<TSource, int> selector)
{
    "int".Dump();
}

static void Foo<TSource>(TSource element, Func<TSource, double> selector)
{
    "double".Dump();
}

static T Identity<T>(T value)
{
    return value;
}
```

(C# 4, tested in LINQPad)

If I try to call `Foo` with a lambda expression as the selector, everything works fine:

```
Foo(42, x => x); // prints "int"
```

But if I replace `x => x` with `Identity`, the compiler can't decide between the 2 `Foo` overloads:

```
Foo(42, Identity);
// The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
// 'UserQuery.Foo<int>(int, System.Func<int,int>)' and
// 'UserQuery.Foo<int>(int, System.Func<int,double>)'
```

How can the second overload be a valid candidate ? Type inference correctly determines that `TSource` is `int`, so the `T` parameter for the `Identity` method has to be `int` as well, so the return type has to be `int` too... `Identity` could be a `Func<int,int>` or a `Func<double,double>`, but not a `Func<int,double>`!

And it gets worse! Even if I specify all type parameters explicitly, I still get the same error:

```
Foo<int>(42, Identity<int>); // The call is ambiguous...
```

How can there be any ambiguity here? As far as I can tell, there is no way the overload that takes a `Func<int,double>` can be a candidate. I guess the explanation must be somewhere in the specifications, but I can't find the relevant bit... or it might be a bug in the compiler, but I guess it's unlikely.

Note that it does work if I explicitly create the delegate:

```
Foo(42, new Func<int, int>(Identity)); // prints "int"
```

So, could someone explain what's going on here? Also, why does it work with a lambda but not with a method group?

Comment: Patiently waiting for Eric Lippert to post *the* answer.

Comment: What happens under C# 3? I suspect this may have something to do with type variance in generics.

Comment: @Anon, I didn't try with C#3, but I don't think it has anything to do with variance, because variance doesn't apply to value types

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I agree, that's a dup... I didn't know what to search for ;)

Comment: I've posted a new analysis to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it simply because the return type isn't part of the method's signature?

The fact that the `Identity<T>` method's argument type and return type are guaranteed to be the same isn't taken into account by the compiler when attempting to decide which overload of `Foo<TSource>` is required. If the return type isn't considered then `Identity<int>` could equally be convertible to `Func<int, int>`, `Func<int, double>` or `Func<int, anything>`.

Comment: I think that this is it. Let's see what Eric will say about this one!

Comment: Good point, I forgot that the return type wasn't part of the signature...

Answer (score 1):

I think that LukeH is correct. However, to answer the second bit of your question: the delegate of the lambda will already have all types filled in (e.g. always be a `Func<int, int>` if `TSource` is an `int`), which is why there is no ambiguity in that case. It's not like a function signature where the return type is ignored.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the correct explanation...

Comment: Absolutely not.  Lambdas are highly context sensitive.  In fact, the lambda version IS ambiguous.  http://ideone.com/IpUmb

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I don't understand what you mean... what is this code supposed to illustrate? It works fine with a lambda, so it must be unambiguous...

Comment: It shows that the lambda you gave is perfectly usable with the "double" function.