# Lambda expression syntactic sugar?

Tags: c#, lambda, syntactic-sugar

I have just come across the following code (.NET 3.5), which doesn't look like it should compile to me, but it does, and works fine:

```
bool b = selectedTables.Any(table1.IsChildOf));
```

Table.IsChildOf is actually a method with following signature:

```
public bool IsChildOf(Table otherTable)
```

Am I right in thinking this is equivalent to:

```
bool b = selectedTables.Any(a => table1.IsChildOf(a));
```

and if so, what is the proper term for this?

Comment: it could be connected to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245012/simple-linq-expression-wont-compile/5245066#5245066

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a *method group conversion*, and it's been available since C# 2. As a simpler example, consider:

```
public void Foo()
{
}

...

ThreadStart x = Foo;
ThreadStart y = new ThreadStart(Foo); // Equivalent code
```

Note that this is *not* quite the same as the lambda expression version, which will capture the *variable* `table1`, and generate a new class with a method in which just calls `IsChildOf`. For `Any` that isn't important, but the difference *would* be important for `Where`:

```
var usingMethodGroup = selectedTables.Where(table1.IsChildOf);
var usingLambda = selectedTables.Where(x => table1.IsChildOf(x));
table1 = null;

// Fine: the *value* of `table1` was used to create the delegate
Console.WriteLine(usingMethodGroup.Count());

// Bang! The lambda expression will try to call IsChildOf on a null reference
Console.WriteLine(usingLambda.Count());
```

Comment: do you mean that the first one is a closure, while the lambda is not?

Comment: @Can: Other way round - the lambda is a closure, capturing table1.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. These things easily get confusing:) This will also be a closure, right?

selectedTables.Where(delegate(Table table) { return table1.IsChildOf(table); });

Comment: @Can: Yes - that's an *anonymous method* from C# 2. Lambda expressions in C# 3 have almost completely replaced anonymous methods.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `table1.IsChildOf` is called a [*method group*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886822/50079).

You are right in that it is equivalent, and indeed this is syntactic sugar.

Comment: It's not really equivalent - for Any the results will be the same (unless there's another thread involved changing the value of table1) but in general there can be a significant difference. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @Jon: You are certainly right, and your explanation of what goes on behind the scenes is very valuable. But in my defense, changing the value of `table1` before the query is enumerated is something you don't see every day.

Comment: @Jon: True, but given the lazy nature of many LINQ operators, I think it's important to understand how capturing works (vs method group conversion).

Comment: @Jon: Agreed. Now if only we could get everyone to understand closure... ;)

Comment: @Jon and @Jon, Resharper used to have a bug that fell into the exact pitfal Mr Skeet is pointing out. `Event1 += (o, e) => Event2(o, e);` will "chain" events, causing `Event2` to fire whenever `Event1` fires. But Resharper would happily suggest the alternative `Event1 += Event2`, which is totally different: it immediately copies any handlers *currently* in `Event2` on to `Event1`'s list. Typically the result is that the events don't get passed on as expected (because `Event2` might still be an empty list at the time when the copy occurs).

Comment: Er, when I say "exact", maybe "analogous" would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a method group. Resharper encourages this kind of code.