# Compiler error when replacing Lambda expression with method group

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I love the Linq syntax and its power, but sometimes I just can't understand why things work as they work.

Like right now. I have the following piece of code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex( ... );

int result1 = stringList.Count(regex.IsMatch);
IEnumerable<string> result2 = stringList.Where (x => regex.IsMatch (x));
```

As you can see in the first query I can use the shorter method group 'regex.IsMatch', but in the second query I have to write 'x => regex.IsMatch (x)'.

As Count and Where both take the same argument of type

```
Func<string, bool>
```

I can't see why I get a compiler error when I do this:

```
IEnumerable<string> result2 = stringList.Where (regex.IsMatch);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, this is an overload resolution issue.

`Count` has only one overload that takes two arguments (extended argument + predicate), but `Where` has two (one where the predicate considers the item-index, and one that doesn't). To complicate matters, `Regex.IsMatch` has multiple overloads of its own. 
Now it turns out that the compiler is correct to complain about ambiguity since *two* of these overloads of `IsMatch` are genuinely applicable (each one is compatible with a different overload of `Where`):

```
// Where overload without item-index
Regex.IsMatch(string) is compatible with Where<string>(string, Func<string, bool>)

// Where overload with item-index
Regex.IsMatch(string, int) is compatible with Where<string>(string, Func<string, int, bool>)
```

...but there can be other related cases involving method-groups (when return-type analysis is required) where the [compiler can complain about ambiguity  even when there is no ambiguity for a human](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203792/overloaded-method-group-argument-confuses-overload-resolution).

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense now :)