# Why do Func/Lambdas resolve by return type for method overload, while method doesn't?

Tags: c#, delegates, overloading, lambda

I've defined these method overloads, differing only by Action/Func parameter:

```
    public void DoSomethingWithValues(Action<decimal, decimal> d, decimal x, decimal y)
    {
        d(x, y);
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithValues(Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> d, decimal x, decimal y)
    {
        var value = d(x, y);
    }
```

I try to call them via inline lambda, Func<>, and a Method:

```
    public Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> ImAFuncWhichDoesSomething = (x, y) => (x + y) / 5;

    public decimal ImAMethodWhichDoesSomething(decimal x, decimal y)
    {
        return (x + y + 17) / 12;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingWithValues((x, y) => (x - y) / 17 , 1, 2);       // Inline lambda compiles OK
        DoSomethingWithValues(ImAFuncWhichDoesSomething, 1, 2);     // Func<> compiles OK
        DoSomethingWithValues(ImAMethodWhichDoesSomething, 1, 2);   // Method generates "ambiguous invocation" error!!
    }
```

The first two compile fine and resolve by the return type.

However the Method doesn't compile due to "Ambiguous invocation" error!

Why does a lambda/func resolve the overload by return type, while a method doesn't?

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203792/412770
"Lambda conversions do take into account the compatibility of the returned expression's type with the target delegate's return type. It is unfortunate that method groups and lambda expressions use two subtly different algorithms for determining convertibility, but we're stuck with it now. Remember, method group conversions have been in the language a lot longer than lambda conversions; had they been added at the same time, I imagine that their rules would have been made consistent."

Comment: I'd accept that as the answer if you posted it.