# Converting an extension method group to a delegate with a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, extension-methods, internals

I have two extension methods on IDataReader with the following signatures:

```
internal static List<T> GetList<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<string, T> del)

internal static double? GetDoubleOrNull(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
```

`GetDoubleOrNull` does not have any overloads.

Elsewhere, I'm able to do

```
Func<string, double?> del = reader.GetDoubleOrNull;

var x = reader.GetList(del);
```

or

```
var x = reader.GetList<double?>(reader.GetDoubleOrNull);
```

or just pass in an instance method like

```
public double? blah(string s)

var x = reader.GetList(blah);
```

but I can't do

```
var x = reader.GetList(reader.GetDoubleOrNull);
```

The compiler gives the error

```
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Func<string,double?>'
```

I don't understand this. I thought that since there's no overload on `GetDoubleOrNull`, there wouldn't be an overload resolution and it could infer the type parameter from the method signature.

The really confusing part is how it seems to work when passing in `blah`.

Comment: Very interesting. An explicit cast ``var x = reader.GetList((Func<string, double?>)reader.GetDoubleOrNull)`` also works. Resharper marks the cast as redundant, but without it compilation fails. Is Jon Skeet around?

Comment: Is there a way to invoke Jon Skeet (or maybe Eric Lippert)? Say their name three times or something?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745852/method-inference-does-not-work-with-method-group and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057146/compiler-ambiguous-invocation-error-anonymous-method-and-method-group-with-fun

Answer (score 8):

*Preface: Skip to the edit if you want the complete explanation. Spoiler: **Extension Methods are a compiler trick, and actually have one more argument than they look like when you invoke them**.*

It's in the resolution of the method group. Apparently the C# compiler doesn't take the time to figure out whether the method you are using has overloads or not; it just always requires an explicit cast. Check out:

[What is a method group in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c)
[Method Inference does not work with method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745852/method-inference-does-not-work-with-method-group)

The method group that comes back from `reader.GetDoubleOrNull` is narrowed down by what you try to cast it to: `GetDoubleOrNull` could refer to any number of overloaded methods with that name. You must explicitly cast it.

Interestingly, you can't even assign a method group to an implicitly-typed variable for the same reason:

```
var x = reader.GetDoubleOrNull;
```

fails to compile because it requires an explicit cast.

**Edit** I'm pretty sure that the confusion here has to do with extension methods:

Check out the following test class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> GetList<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<string, T> del)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static double? GetDoubleOrNull(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static double? blah(this string s)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can successfully call

```
var x = reader.GetList(Extensions.blah);
```

*Why could this be*? `blah` is a static extension method as well, so, based on your evidence, it would seem like the above line should not compile. Further complicating things, let's add this method:

```
public static List<T> GetList2<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<IDataReader, string, T> del) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

You can now call

```
x = reader.GetList2(Extensions.GetDoubleOrNull);
```

and it will compile properly. What gives?

**Here's the answer: Extension Methods do not *actually* add methods to your objects.** They're really a compiler trick to allow you to program as if those methods were part of your classes. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

> In your code you invoke the extension method with instance method
>   syntax. However, the intermediate language (IL) generated by the
>   compiler translates your code into a call on the static method.
>   Therefore, the principle of encapsulation is not really being
>   violated. In fact, extension methods cannot access private variables
>   in the type they are extending.

So, when you call

```
var x = reader.GetDoubleOrNull("myColumnName");
```

what is actually being compiled and executed is essentially this (a perfectly legitimate call, even though it's an extension method):

```
var x = Extensions.GetDoubleOrNull(reader, "myColumnName");
```

So, when you try to use `GetDoubleOrNull` as an arg for a `Func<string, double?>`, the compiler is going "I can turn `GetDoubleOrNull` into a `Func<IDataReader, string, double?>` because it has two arguments, but I don't know how to turn it into a `Func<string, double?>`"

**Even though you're calling it as if it's an instance method of the `IDataReader` with one arg, it is not**: it's just a static method with two args that the C# compiler has tricked you into thinking is part of `IDataReader`.

Comment: Excellent answer and research. I want to +1 it again. ;-)

Comment: I'm not Jon Skeet, but I do what I can :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately still I don't seem to understand the issue clearly.

The first question you referenced is one that I'm aware of. I read the second one, as well as those posted by AakashM, and it looks to me that it comes down to how overload resolution doesn't take return types into account. I understand that.

But how, then, does passing in `blah` work? Is there no overload resolution that takes place in that case? If not, why not? If so, how is it that it succeeds?

Comment: Doesn't need to resolve it you told it what to do with public double? blah(string s);

Comment: @Moss: I updated the answer to explain with a little more clarity.

Comment: @eouw0o83hf Now it's much clearer, thanks. Let's take it one step further though. While I can do `x = reader.GetList2(Extensions.GetDoubleOrNull);`, I still can't do `var x = reader.GetList2(reader.GetDoubleOrNull);`. I get a "type argument cannot be inferred from usage" error.

Comment: This is weird: `var x = reader.GetList<double?>(reader.GetDoubleOrNull);` also works. :S

Comment: I think it's a bug in the version 4 compiler. In version 5 this compiles just fine. (Of course we did not know that when the question was asked)

Answer (score 0):

GetDoubleOrNull returns a double?
GetList expects an IDataReader and a `System.Func<string,int?>`

The error message is a tad misleading

public double? blah(string s)

var x = reader.GetList(blah);

blah is a delegate in this call. In GetList(GetDoubleOrNull) it's the result of get doubleOrNull.

Good question though. Do post the answer wwhether I've helped or not.

Comment: The ``int`` must be a typo, changing it to ``double`` still gives the compiler error.

Comment: You said "In GetList(GetDoubleOrNull) it's the result of get doubleOrNull" but this is not right. In this case `GetDoubleOrNull` is not being evaluated, it is being treated as a method group.

Comment: Never meant it was being evaluated. What's the signature of GetDoubleOrNull, compared to the argument of GetList.