# Why is the compiler not able to infer the type of the method?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

In the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public decimal Decimal { get; set; }
}

public decimal Test()
{
    return new List<A>().Sum(SumDecimal);
}

public decimal SumDecimal(A a)
{
    return a.Decimal;
}
```

The line `return new List<A>().Sum(SumDecimal);` has an error stating that the `SumDecimal` is an ambiguous invocation.

Why isn't the compiler able to infer the type of `SumDecimal`. The following works, however:

```
return new List<A>().Sum((Func<A, decimal>) SumDecimal);
```

And of course, the usual lambda way works too:

```
return new List<A>().Sum(x => SumDecimal(x));
```

On more experimentation, if I write an extension method of my own:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T MySum<T, T2>(this IEnumerable<T2> ie, Func<T2, T> d)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

and call that, the compiler infers just fine:

```
return new List<A>().MySum(SumDecimal);
```

I see that `IEnumerable<T>.Sum` is overloaded for `int`, `decimal` etc:

```
public static int Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
{
  return Enumerable.Sum(Enumerable.Select<TSource, int>(source, selector));
}
```

and not like how I have defined. But still, is it just that the compiler's type inference is weak and it is not able to figure it out?

Comment: Not that it helps but this also works: return new List<A>().Sum(x => SumDecimal(x));  For some reason it is only using the method group that doesn't work.

Comment: @DoctorMick - That is how I usually start writing, and change it to the method group. I was surprised to know that this causes an error here.

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be getting ambiguity between `System.Func<A,decimal>)` and `System.Func<A,decimal?>)`

Comment: This also works (and uses the more common lambda syntax): `return new List<A>().Sum(a => SumDecimal(a));`

Comment: If no one else takes this one I'll post an answer when I get to the office. Its too complicated to type out on this phone.

Comment: Think this is similar to @EricLippert's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745852/method-inference-does-not-work-with-method-group basically the return type is not considered in overload resolution for method groups.

Comment: Doesn't this go back to Eric's [Delegates and Structural Identity](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/06/18/delegates-structural-identity/#.) post - without asking the compiler to generate a lambda, you're left with two incompatible delegate types.

Comment: Seems an exact dupe of @KevinHolditch 's suggestion. If I 'm wrong and noone with a gold C# badge gets to reopen first, ping me and I 'll do it myself.

Comment: @KevinHolditch is correct -- this is a dupe. Thanks Kevin!

Comment: @KevinHolditch - Thanks for the link. It was difficult to search for it.