# Why is Foo(Action bar) and Foo(Func<Task> bar) ambiguous when used with method groups?

Tags: c#, overload-resolution

I just stumbled on the following behavior, which I don't see the motivation for.

Consider the following methods:

```
void Foo(Action bar)
{
     bar();
     Console.WriteLine("action");
}

async Task Foo(Func<Task> bar)
{
    await bar();
    Console.WriteLine("func");
}

void Bar()
{
}
```

This definition causes a compiler error, stating that the call to `Foo` is ambiguous between the two methods:

```
void Baz()
{
    Foo(Bar); // <-- compiler error here
}
```

However, this works fine:

```
void Baz()
{
    Foo(() => Bar());
}
```

Why is this even ambiguous (`Bar()` doesn't return a `Task`, so `Bar` shouldn't be a `Func<Task>`)? Why does it work when I use a lambda expression instead of a method group?

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745852