# C# Task Return Value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'am making an application in C# .Net 4.5. I am trying to use multithreading, via tasks. I have an array of tasks that I get to run some process. I want the task to return a enumeration which is called enumSignal. However I do not know what to do, the below code is my attempt.

It highlights the line "_taskFactory.StartNew(_indicator[I].Run)" with the message The call is ambiguous between the following methods.

```
 public void RunIndicators()
        {
            _taskFactory = new TaskFactory();

            Task<enumSignal>[] taskIndicator = new Task<enumSignal>[_indicator.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < taskIndicator.Length; i++)
            {

                taskIndicator[i] = _taskFactory.StartNew(_indicator[i].Run);

            }
            Task.WaitAll(taskIndicator);
        }
```

Comment: do you have two StartNew methods in TaskFactory?

Comment: What is the type of `_indicator[i].Run`?

Comment: yes that's what is says but I don't understand why. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<Simulator.enumSignal>(System.Func<Simulator.enumSignal>) and System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(System.Action)

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# .net why does Task.Run seem to handle Func<T> differently than other code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695886/c-sharp-net-why-does-task-run-seem-to-handle-funct-differently-than-other-cod)

Comment: _indicator[I].Run should return enumSignal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# compiler can't always infer generic delegate types when multiple overloads exist.  Try adjusting your `StartNew()` call as follows:

```
_taskFactory.StartNew((Func<enumSignal>)_indicator[i].Run)
```

...or, if you prefer:

```
_taskFactory.StartNew<enumSignal>(_indicator[i].Run)
```

This assumes `_indicator[i].Run()` has no arguments and returns an `enumSignal`.